# Bootstrap Theme error: Problem with setting the color scheme

Tags: css, sass, themes, color-scheme, bootstrap-themes

I'm designing a webpage for my non-profit association, and to make things easier I buyed a bootstrap theme template (Leap Bootstrap Theme).

In the main folder of my project, I have the following folders:

/dist
/forms
/js
/node_modules
/pages
/scss

Inside the '/scss' folder, in order to modify the color scheme of the theme, to set the colors I want, I have to modify the file '/scss/user-variables.css' in that way:

```
// 
// 
// user-variables.scss
//
// Place your own variable overrides here, these will override any Bootstrap and theme variables.


// Color Scheme
// Uncomment the variables below and change the hex values.

$primary: #3D3B3C;
$primary-2: #FDFDB7;
$primary-3: #3D3B3C;

// Do not change or remove the $theme-color-scheme or $theme-colors maps below

$theme-color-scheme: (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "primary-2":  $primary-2,
    "primary-3":  $primary-3
);

$theme-colors: (
    "primary":    $primary,
    "primary-2":  $primary-2,
    "primary-3":  $primary-3,
);
```

The 'index.html' file is inside the '/pages' folder, with other folders (css, js, img, fonts, ...).

When I'm making these changes with gulp and browsersync, it is showed the rightful color scheme that I want (as I coded into the user-variables.css file).

The problem is when I upload the files into the web hosting server. When I access to the website, I still see the original color scheme of the bootstrap theme instead of the colours I set. What is corious, is some external users view the rightful colours.

Inside the 'public' folder I only upload the 'index.html' file and the '/assets' folder. Do I have to upload that 'user-variables.css' file, and where?

Could you help me with that problem? Sorry, but I'm new in this world.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this fixed the error, but you have an extra comma here `"primary-3":  $primary-3,`, try removing it and see if it works

Comment: No, that comma didn't fix the error. But thank you, anyways! :)

Comment: If other users see the right colors, try bumping your css. It might be cached in your browser.

Comment: The URL of the website:

[link](http://www.granotsisopes.cat/)

What color do you see? Blue or black-lighted? What do you mean with bumping my css?

Comment: @MatiesAlzinaSoler can you tell me the colors you want to change with these colors ?

Comment: your site footer and header are #3D3B3C;

Comment: The colors that I want are:

$primary: #3D3B3C;
$primary-2: #FDFDB7;
$primary-3: #3D3B3C;

Comment: The color you said were right. So you are viewing my website as it should. Does the error come from the navigator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my part, your site is illuminated black.
Maties Alzina Soler wants to tell you to clear your cache, I suppose.
To do this, press SHIFT + F5 or Ctrl + F5 on your site.

Comment: I cleaned all navigator data from the PC, and now I see the right colours. But I'm still seeing the wrong colours from my mobile and Ipad, despite of having cleaned the navigator data.

Comment: Your problem always comes from the css cache, but this time from your phone.
 https://doctolib.zendesk.com/hc/fr/articles/208440616-Vider-le-cache-du-navigateur-sur-mobile

If it really doesn't change anything, try tools like CCleaner.